# problem with node sass npm package node modules

Tags: node.js, npm, command-line, node-modules, npm-install

npm package installation problem from command line, general problem on several packages since the node sass installation attempt which did not install what to do now it blocks all package installations what happend??

i have uninstalled and reinstalled node it is still blocking npm, moreover it is very slow to give me the errors. something has happened and i don't know what.

```
 Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Tous droits réservés.

Testez le nouveau système multiplateforme PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Users\opsty> npm -v
6.14.8
PS C:\Users\opsty> npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/windows-build-tools failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 93.184.216.34:8080
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\opsty\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-30T08_31_04_559Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\opsty> npm install -g @angular/cli
npm WARN registry Unexpected warning for https://registry.npmjs.org/: Miscellaneous Warning ETIMEDOUT: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2fcli failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 93.184.216.34:8080
npm WARN registry Using stale data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular/cli/-/cli-10.2.0.tgz failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 93.184.216.34:8080
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\opsty\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-30T08_37_03_772Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\opsty> npm install node-gyp
npm WARN registry Unexpected warning for https://registry.npmjs.org/: Miscellaneous Warning ETIMEDOUT: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/node-gyp failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 93.184.216.34:8080
npm WARN registry Using stale data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/node-gyp/-/node-gyp-7.1.2.tgz failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 93.184.216.34:8080
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\opsty\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-30T08_43_11_642Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\opsty>
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not look like node or npm issue. Could it be your DNS server misbehaving?

In other words, when you see errors like this firstly you would need to make sure your computer can talk to the https://registry.npmjs.org/ DNS name and 93.184.216.34 IP address.

Comment: and where should I go to see this? and what to do as manipulations? I have no idea of ​​the procedure to follow

Answer (score 0):

problem solved so I did a npm config delete proxy npm config delete htpp-proxy there are several methods

```
npm config delete proxy
npm config delete http-proxy
npm config delete https-proxy

npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy

npm config delete http-proxy
npm config delete https-proxy
```